# How Listen to an smart contract event using web3 and angular?

Tags: solidity, web3js, angular2

I am using web3@0.20 inside angular to call smart contract functions,

I want to know how to watch a smart contract event in angular?

using javascript is easy and it works :

```
sEvent.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error)
        {
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use .watch and it works also in angular,

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap everything inside a service and use an observable to update the component and so its UI

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the full answer to your question in this course :
https://www.udemy.com/blockchain-ninja-develop-ethereum-dapp-with-angular/
but in my opinion you can start by using an Event Listener function.